# Usage about the grammar between inf. "To V" and "Ving"

Tags: grammar

It's my first time to use this platform.

Are the sentences below correct?

1. The sentence "I decided to quit the job." equal the other sentence "I decided quitting the job."?
2. The sentence "My aim in life is to become a singer." equal the other sentence "My aim in life is becoming a singer."?
3. The sentence "She got her husband to clean up the house." equal the other sentence "She got her husband cleaning up the house."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part of the first example is ungrammatical. The only way you could make make it work would be to insert 'on' to turn it into "I decided *on* quitting the job" but this is only approximately the same as "I decided to quit the job." You would use the "decided on" sentence to talk about a choice between two or more options. For instance "I thought about asking for a pay rise or quitting the job, I decided on quitting the job"

The first and second parts of the second example are both grammatical and are very close in menaing but the second one is a bit more clumsy and less likely to be used in my opinion.

Both parts of the third example are grammatical but there is a slight difference in meaning: The first one usually means that she got her husband to clean the house once, the second usually means that she got her husband to clean the house on a regular basis.

On another point you use the sentence "Are these above sentence correct?" to pose your question. This is wrong in two ways: firstly you should use the plural form *sentences* to refer to more than one sentence and secondly you should only use *above* in a sentence like this if the things being referred to come first. You should have said "Are the following sentences correct?" or "Are the sentences below correct?"

Comment: Wow! Your analysis is very detailed! Thank you very much! I appreciate it.

Comment: @KantLin Thank you for the comment and for accepting my answer. At EL&U we try to answer comprehensively if we can, often with references to back up what we have said. If I'd given a very short answer with no explanation another contributor would have downvoted my answer as being inadequate. I hope you have enjoyed your experience here.